# On the limit of the sum of positive sequences

Tags: calculus

Suppose that $a_n$ and $b_n$ are two *positive* sequences of real numbers. Let us also suppose that $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n + b_n$ exists finite. Is it true that both the limit of $a_n$ and $b_n$ exist finite?

Comment: It is true that both sequences are bounded.  But convergent not so much.  If one is convergent than the other is... but that's pretty obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: Consider the sequences

$$ (a_n) = 1, \frac{1}{2}, 1, \frac{1}{2}, \dots, \\
(b_n) = \frac{1}{2}, 1, \frac{1}{2}, 1, \dots. $$

Comment: This is not an hint. This is a counterexample :-) Thanks.